# Return outside function error - help needed

Tags: python, return

```
def getPressAve(odbname):
    odb=openOdb(odbname)
    lastFrame=odb.steps['Step-1'].frames[-1]
    pressure=lastFrame.fieldOutputs['CPRESS']
    press=[[0,0]] # sets the first element to [0,0]

    for n in pressure.values:
      gridPt=part1.nodes.getFromLabel(n.nodeLabel)

      coord=assemb.getCoordinates(gridPt)
      press.append([n.nodeLabel,n.data,coord])
      press=avePress=press[1:] # removes the first element
      press.sort(Comp_X)
      print ('pressure extracted')

      index=0
      while index<len(press):
        sum=0
        tally=0

        if index!=0:
          sum=sum+press[index-1][1]
        tally=tally+1

        if index!=1:
          sum=sum+press[index-2][1]
        tally=tally+1

        if index!=2:
          sum=sum+press[index][1]
        tally=tally+1

        if index<len(press)-1:
          sum=sum+press[index+1][1]
        tally=tally+1

        if index<len(press)-2:
          sum=sum+press[index+2][1]
        tally=tally+1

        average=sum/tally
        avePress[index][1]=average
        index=index+1

    odb.close()
    print ('pressure averaged')
    return avePress
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python, indentation matters. As is, you're defining a function called `getPressAve` which does only this:

```
odb=openOdb(odbname)
```

After you've defined your function, you go on to do

```
lastFrame=odb.steps['Step-1'].frames[-1]
```

and such *outside of the function*. That's not what you want. The solution is to indent everything after that `odb=openOdb(odbname)` line to that level, so those lines are interpreted as being part of the body of the function.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to properly indent your code:

```
def getPressAve(odbname):
    odb=openOdb(odbname)
    ...
    print ('pressure averaged')
    return avePress
```

As yours has not been, the `return` keyword is featured outside of a function, and hence the error: `SyntaxError: 'return' outside function`.